# How to implement such UI with TableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

The UI I want to implement:

[image]

I wonder how to implement the top view (contains image and description, etc.) without TableCell border.
The first idea for it is use tableHeaderView.

But if I want to implement such view not only at the top but in the middle of the tableView, any other solutions for such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create your custom tableViewCell and implement your own display logic either in IB or programmatically.

What you need to is creating a class which is a subclass of UITableViewCell.
Check these tutorials.

http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/how-to-design-a-custom-uitableviewcell-from-scratch/1292/

http://zcentric.com/2008/08/05/custom-uitableviewcell/

Comment: How to hide the tableCell border when tableStyle is group? I don't want the system tableCell border in this view.

Comment: To remove borders of tableCell use this tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: I mean the round border not the separator line. But I got some idea, I can use CALayer to hide the TableCell border and clear the background of the tableCell to implement the required view. Thanks Serdar:)

Comment: Like i said create your own implementation of UITableViewCell and apply your display logic there instead of asking me.